# Why is "contains" or "in" not working in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I'm currently working on a project with different functions.
One of the functions is supposed to take a map and a string as inputs, then compare the items in the map and string and create a new map with matching items.
This function is not working because "containsKey" always returns false.
"in" always returns fault.
I tried substituting the map with a mutable List and got the same results.
I tried this same code on kotlin playground, link; https://pl.kotl.in/zZm1Smz3Z
and it worked well but wouldn't work on the platform I am using.

The function is below

```
fun createVariable (stringList: String, mapNumber: MutableMap<String, String>):MutableMap<String, String>  {
    var mapOfNumber = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    var conList : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    var regex = Regex("\\s*=\\s*")
    var regez = Regex("\\s+")
    var numberList = stringList.split(regex).toMutableList()
    for (i in 0.. numberList.size -1) {
        if ( regez.matches(numberList[i])) {
            numberList.removeAt(i) 
       }  
    } 
     if (mapNumber.containsKey(numberList[1])) {
         mapOfNumber.put(numberList[0], (mapNumber[numberList[1]])?: "0") 
       }
       print(mapOfNumber)

   return mapOfNumber
}
```

Comment: write a few debug logs in your code and check if your map or list or whatever actually contains what you think it contains. I'm willing to bet that your code is not working, rather than "'contains' or 'in' not working in Kotlin".

Comment: Could you provide an example input, and an expected output for this? The regex seems very suspicious, and it is hard to figure out what you are trying to accomplish without those examples. Thanks

Comment: If you want to test it on Kotlin Playground, use the same sample data you're using where it's failing. Like Alex says, check you're *actually* getting the data you expect - if you debug the app (stick a breakpoint at the start of the function) you can inspect the variables and make sure the right things are happening. Also make sure if you use `in` you're doing it the right way round - `if (numberList[1] in mapNumber)`